# Case insensitive auto complete in android

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-emulator

I am using the example from http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html. Is there a way i can make it case insensitive ? I dont want to double my array size by adding every possible version of the string.

PS : Is there a way i can manage non English text in here? My android keyboard is English.

Answer (score 3):

I feel this link will help you,
[Custom AutoComplete Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4027085/1089811)

In this approach you define a custom adapter for being used in the AutoCompleteTextView, this adapter is filtered by a custom filter which is also define by you.

I have tried this and it works.

I hope it helps..

Comment: That resource looks pretty complicated. I wonder why we need another class and 60 lines of code for this task. Would have loved something like 'android:caseInsensitive:"true"'

Comment: The situation that I used it for was much more complicated than what you face, I just thought that it will also serve as a solution to you problem as well, this approach potential to do much more than what you require.