# How to implement getFilter on a BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, filter, baseadapter

I am trying to implement a getFilter() on a base adapter to filter out search results on a List. Is there any example of how to implement a getFilter()?

MainActivity.java

```
   final AppInfoAdapter adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this, Utilities.getSystemFilteredApplication(this), getPackageManager());


        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
           adapter.getFilter().filter(s); //Filter from my adapter
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Update my view
        }
```

AppInfoAdapter.java

```
package com.example.permission;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    private Context mContext;
    private List mListAppInfo;
    PackageManager mPackManager;

    public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List list, PackageManager pm) {
        mContext = c;
        mListAppInfo = list;
        mPackManager = pm;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the selected entry
        ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);

        // reference to convertView
        View v = convertView;

        // inflate new layout if null
        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
        }

        // load controls from layout resources
        ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        TextView tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvPkgName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);

        // set data to display
        ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
        tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
        tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);

        // return view
        return v;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

EDIT: Edited the code and added full AppInfoAdapter.java

Answer (score 7):

**in your adapter put this class to use it in getfilter method**

```
//this is a simple class that filtering the ArrayList of strings used in adapter

public class filter_here extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();
            // if constraint is empty return the original names
            if(constraint.length() == 0 ){
                Result.values = Original_Names;
                Result.count = Original_Names.size();
                return Result;
            }

            ArrayList<String> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<String>();
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            String filterableString;

            for(int i = 0; i<Original_Names.size(); i++){
                filterableString = Original_Names.get(i);
                if(filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)){
                    Filtered_Names.add(filterableString);
                }
            }
            Result.values = Filtered_Names;
            Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();

            return Result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Names = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

**return instance from it in getfilter**

```
@Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return filter;
    }
```

[full example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456525/how-to-filter-listview-using-getfilter-in-baseadapter/14359161#14359161)

Answer (score 5):

this almost got me killed :)

1. implement your BaseAdapter like this:
2. define an ArrayList of List in your public adapter class which is gonna contain temporary items of your Original List.

   ```
   public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

       public static ArrayList<String> temporarylist;
       public static ArrayList<String> OriginalList;
       private Activity activity;

       public MyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> OriginalList) {
            super();
            this.activity=activity;
            this.OriginalList = OriginalList;
            temporarylist=OriginalList;

       }
       .
       .
       .
   ```
3. create getFilter() method with the following code[as an example]:

   ```
   public Filter getFilter() {
       Filter filter = new Filter() {

       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       @Override
       protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
           temporarylist=(ArrayList<String>)results.values;
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       }

       @Override
       protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
           FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
           ArrayList<String> FilteredList= new ArrayList<String>();
           if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
               // No filter implemented we return all the list
               results.values = OriginalList;
               results.count = OriginalList.size();
           }
           else {
               for (int i = 0; i < OriginalList.size(); i++) {
                   String data = OriginalList.get(i);
                   if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()))  {
                       FilteredList.add(data);
                   }
               }
               results.values = FilteredList;
               results.count = FilteredList.size();
           }
           return results;
       }
   };
   return filter;
   }
   ```

And finally in your activity for your EditText:

```
MyAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> items;


ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
items = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0;i<30;i++){
     items.add("Hello world "+String.valueof(i));
}
adapter = new GameAdapter(this, items);
list.setAdapter(adapter);


EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search_txt);
     inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MyActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your full `AppInfoAdapter`? Also is there any reason extending from `BaseAdapter` and not `ArrayAdapter`? If you have an `ArrayList` of objects, use `ArrayAdapter`, it already implements `Filterable` interface.

Actually you are using a `List`, your adapter can be rewritten to extends `ArrayAdapter` which already is `Filterable`.

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {

    private Context mContext;
    PackageManager mPackManager;

    public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List<ApplicationInfo> list, PackageManager pm) {
        super(c, 0, new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>());
        mContext = c;
        mPackManager = pm;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // get the selected entry
        ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) getItem(position);

        // reference to convertView
        View v = convertView;

        // inflate new layout if null
        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
        }

        // load controls from layout resources
        ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        TextView tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvPkgName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);

        // set data to display
        ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
        tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
        tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);

        // return view
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited answer so your adapter `extends Filterable ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: There is no errors with your code, but now i don't see my list of installed applications already only the EditText

Comment: Replace `super(c, 0, new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>());` with `super(c, 0, list);` My fault.

Comment: The search works partially, can't really understand how it is working now it is a little buggy so far it only works for the keyword 'android'

Comment: See `ArrayAdapter` source to see how `ArrayFilter` works https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java or this may help also http://stackoverflow.com/a/4027085/1300995

Comment: Yea saw those examples a couple of times but can't really see what's wrong with my code atm, my current mainactivity.java - http://pastebin.com/BJWiWgcd

Comment: It's most probably because `ArrayFilter` uses `toString()` for filtering and `ApplicationInfo.toString()` may give you not what you want.

Comment: Added a few debugging messages, the ontextchanged is working fine but i don't really know how to check whether ApplicationInfo.toString() is giving me the correct information. I just did a         
ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) getItem(position);

        Log.e("TAG", entry.toString());

and a bunch of debugging messages came up when i typed a few characters. Any suggestions for fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an instance of a `Filter`. To write a filter, subclass `Filter` and implement `performFiltering` and `publishResults`. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html).

Answer (score 1):

General procedure

1. Enable text filtering on your ListView
2. Change your baseadapter to store **two** copies of the list, one original, one filtered.
3. Change all access references in your BaseAdapter to refer to the **Filtered list**, not the original.
4. Implement your Filter function in BaseAdapter.

Step 1:
`listview.setTextFilterEnabled(true);`

Step 2:

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    private List mListAppInfo;
    private List mListAppInfoFiltered;

public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List list, PackageManager pm) {
    mContext = c;
    mListAppInfo = list;
    mPackManager = pm;
    mPackManagerFiltered = pm; //added line
}
```

Step 3:

```
public int getCount() {
    return mListAppInfoFiltered.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListAppInfoFiltered.get(position);
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get the selected entry
    ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) mListAppInfoFiltered.get(position);
```

}

Step 4:
I am not sure what type your list is, so assuming a list of String:

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                //no search, so just return all the data
                results.count = mListAppInfo.size();
                results.values = mListAppInfo;
            } else {//do the search
                List<String> resultsData = new ArrayList<>();
                String searchStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                for (String s : mListAppInfo)
                        if (s.toUpperCase().contains(searchStr)) resultsData.add(s);
                    results.count = resultsData.size();
                    results.values = resultsData;
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mListAppInfoFiltered = (ArrayList<MyObject>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getFilter() can be override in adapters and return the filter object which contains filtered list . There are two key methods in Filter() class; **performFiltering** and **publishResults**. The first method performs the filtering in worker thread and the later one return filtered list of objects.

You can refer to sample code below

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (results.count == 0) {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }else{
                    mListAppInfo = (ArrayList<SampleItem>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.values = mListAppInfo;
                    results.count = mListAppInfo.size();
                }else{
                    ArrayList<SampleItem> filter_items = new ArrayList<>(); 
                    for (SampleItem item : mListAppInfo) {
                        if (item.getItemName().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            filter_items.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    results.values =  filter_items ;
                    results.count = filter_items.size();
                }
                return results;
            }
        };
    }
```

Hope you find it useful .

Answer (score -1):

extend your class with ArrayAdapter,then override methods,and create object of filter class and return with it.