# How to programmatically replace a listview by another list view in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

My app has an Activity with an `EditText` and a `ListView`. It works like this: when a character is inserted into EditText a list of words will be populated and displayed in the ListView (i.e, `List_1`).

Here is my working code:

```
//Layout XML
    <LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edWord"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"                
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:hint="@string/edWordText"
            />            
    </LinearLayout>       
</LinearLayout>
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lstWord"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"     
        android:orientation="vertical" />
```

```
//Activity
private ListView lstWord = null; 
private EditText edWord = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = null;  
//OnCreate
lstWord = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstWord);
edWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edWord);
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.customlist);
lstWord.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            //my_stuff
        } 
    });
lstWord.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Now with a new requirement, I would like to add another `ListView (List_2)` to the activity, and the app is set to work as follows:

When the app starts up, it will display the EditText box and **List_2**. Right when a character is input into EditText, **List_2** is removed and **List_1** is shown.

I wonder if this idea is feasible. If YES, how should I programmatically deploy it?

Help highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like autocomplete on a list view? If so, take a look at [this post](http://androidexample.com/Show_AutoComplete_Suggestions_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=105&aaid=127)

Comment: You should just change/update the adapter =) else you can maybe take a look at the interface Filtrable for your adapter (use with baseAdapter)

Comment: @FMontano: Thanks, but I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for. It might be converting current list view to AutoCompleteTextView.

Comment: @Yume117: Can you make it clearer to me?

Comment: the interface Filtrable makes it possible to update a listview in realtime in accordance to criteras. Maybe see other posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17720481/how-could-i-filter-the-listview-using-baseadapter and for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619874/how-to-implement-getfilter-on-a-baseadapter