# show current size of items after filterable in baseadapter

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I am using BaseAdapter with filterable, after the filter, i want to show in the activity the current size of the filteredItems.

The problem is, when I initiate the filter from the adapter, it seems to take a little while (I guess In milliseconds), and from the activity, when I run the method

```
adapter.getSize()
```

It gives me the count before the filter, not after.

for example:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Names = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and from the activity:

```
adapter.filter()....
System.out.println(adapter.getSize()); //return wrong count
```

2 related questions:

1) is the filterable Async or sync?

2) How can i know from the activity, that the filter was done and notifysetchanged() was completed?

P.S the notify set change is inside the adapter, as suggested on this page:

[How to implement getFilter on a BaseAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619874/how-to-implement-getfilter-on-a-baseadapter)

Comment: did you override getSize() 2. the filter is sync 3. notifysetchanged is for the viewed items and you shouldn't care about it or when it's finished but its also sync so just the line after you call it if you are interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that, it works great for me:

```
    int filtered;
    View yourView;
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    yourList= (ArrayList<?>) results.values;
                    filtered = yourList.size();
                    yourView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            yourView.setText("Total " + filtered);
                        }
                    });
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```