# How to use SEARCH FILTER for BaseExpandableListAdapter with List<String> and HashMap<String, ExpandableModel>

Tags: android, list, hashmap

trying to implement searchfilter for my code, I've seen some codes but couldn't adapt to mine
I don't know how to write search filter and adapt to my list
, here is some of my code:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter2Sharh extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private TextView tvDate;
    private TextView tvTime;
    private TextView tvType;
    private TextView tvRequestName;
    private TextView tvRequestSender;
    private TextView tvRequestTitle;
    private TextView tvRequestDescription;
    private TextView tvRequestCoordinate;
    private TextView tvRequestAttachment;
    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, ExpandableModle> expandableListDetail;


public ExpandableListAdapter2Sharh(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                       HashMap<String, ExpandableModle> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Nivad, Please mention what are the tutorials you are following and what did you try so far and where are you stuck. That would help the members answer better.

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, tried the second answer of this  example but I don't  know how filter my data in getfilter method  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619874/how-to-implement-getfilter-on-a-baseadapter